# Jquery appending form elements and values

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I am needing a jquery function that checks the database for the max videos allowed for a specific match type of a specified `matchID` and also the current number of videos already assigned to that particular match.
With this information, I need to construct x amount of inputs (max number of videos for match type) and also populate the inputs where the videos already exist.

For example:

One match could be of type 3 games, which in that case I would need to populate 3 different inputs, also checking to see if the match has videos already existing and filling in those input values with the corresponding video information in order for it to be edited. I completed mostly everything on my own, I have the corresponding inputs displaying fine based on the max amount of videos allowed per that Match Type. The only issue I am having is after generating the inputs, what would be the best way of looping through them based on the `videoEditVideoCount` ( the total number of videos for the specified match )

To sum it all up:
I have a Edit Video Form
--Dropdown Menu to select which match you would like to edit the videos for
---ON change 
---GET max video allowed per match type
---APPEND max video value of inputs to form

```
function populateEditVideo(matchid){
$.ajax({
    url : '/index.php/ajax/populateEditVideo',
    type : 'POST',
    data : {'matchID' : matchid},
    dataType : 'json',
    success : function (result) {
        $("div#videoEdit").empty();  
        for(var i = 1; i <= result['videoEditVideoMax']; i++){
            $('<label for="videoEditYoutubeURL">Video ' + i + '</label><input name="videoEditYoutubeURL'+i+'" id="videoEditYoutubeURL" type="text" maxlength="16" />').appendTo("div#videoEdit");
        }
        for(var i = 1; i <= result['videoEditVideoCount']; i++){
        $("input#videoEditYoutubeURL"+i).css("background-color", "red");
        }
```

Let's say `videoEditVideoCount = 2` and `videoEditVideoMax = 3`
What I would like to do is append 3 text inputs, and then modify the first 2 input values.

Any help would greatly be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Am I just looking at this the wrong way? Should I just gather the information that exist first and then populate any extra available video slots based on that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got the id of the `<input>` elements wrong. You forgot to append the number. This would mean the background colour would not change to red.